# Emacs - open terminal emulator buffer function

Tags: emacs, elisp

I need function that opens terminal emulator buffer if none exists, in that case it switches to that buffer.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<kbd>M-x term</kbd> does exactly that.  Use <kbd>M-u M-x term</kbd> if you want to force a new terminal buffer.

From elisp:

```
(term "/bin/bash")
```

Answer (score 0):

M-x [ansi-term](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AnsiTerm) is more... Well, Ansi. Allow for nifty pretty prompts (BTW take care of not making tramp trip over your fancy color prompt, this bit me just today when a C-x C-f /sudo::root@localhost:/someRootOnlyFile got stuck)